# PHP Undefined Variable - Não consigo atribuir um valor ao POST

Tags: php, html5, php-7

Objetivo é realizar um login através do numero do CPF ou do NIS. Porém não estou conseguindo atribuir valores pelo método POST as variavés $CPF e $NIS e assim o login nunca é realizado.

````
<form class="form" method="POST" action="verificacao.php">


                    <label class="label-input" for="">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock icon-modify"></i>
                        <input type="number" name="CPF" placeholder="CPF" required="required">
                    </label>

                    <label class="label-input" for="">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock icon-modify"></i>
                        <input type="number" name="NIS" placeholder="NIS" required="required">
                    </label>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-second" name="send">Entrar</button>
    </form>
```

Abaixo o restante do código em PHP. Não consigo passar nem mesmo do primeiro "if". Quando tento printar o Array do $POST, ele aparece vazio. 

```
<?php

 print_r($_POST);
     if(isset($_POST['send'])){
     if (isset($_POST['CPF']) || isset($_POST['NIS']))
     {   
        echo "Chegou aqui1" ;

         //verificar se esta preenchido

         if(!empty($CPF) || !empty($NIS))
         {  
            $CPF = addslashes($_POST['CPF']);
            $NIS = addcslashes($_POST['NIS']);

            $u->conectar("cadastrados","localhost", "root","root");
            if($u->msgErro == "")
            {
                if($u->logar($CPF,SNIS))
                {
                    header("location: verificacao.php");
                    echo "Chegou aqui5" ;                   
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "CPF e NIS não encontrados!" ;
                    echo "Chegou aqui4" ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
                echo "Chegou aqui3" ;
            }   
         } 
         else{
             echo "Preencha com número do CPF ou NIS!"; 
             echo "Chegou aqui2" ;
         }

     }
     } 
     ?> 
    ```

Preciso muito de ajuda, se alguém puder me dar uma luz serei muito grato!
````

Comment: É por causa disso`if(isset($_POST['send']))` você não definiu um valor para `<button name='send'>`, então `isset($_POST['send'])` sempre vai ser `false`. Ou você elimina em PHP essa verificação ou em HTML define um valor para elemento.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Olá, Jonatas! Se a resposta foi útil, favor aceitar a resposta! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Nosso amigo [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) está correto em seu comentário!

Você está verificando se a variável **$_POST['send']** está setada, **mas ela não está sendo enviada via POST, pois ela não contém um valor (value) definido**!

1) Defina um valor para o botão "send"

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-second" name="send" value="entrar">Entrar</button>
```

2) Ou verifique somente a variável $_POST

```
if( isset($_POST) ){
```

De qualquer maneira, sugiro pesquisar algo para aumentar a segurança do seu formulário!

Comment: Olá, Jonatas! Se a resposta foi útil, favor avaliar corretamente! Obrigado

Comment: O isset verifica se uma variável foi definida/inicializada, não é verificado se possuí um valor. O isset sempre vai retornar true para $_POST porque ele vai estar sempre definido

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo se no formulário HTML não estiver VALUE definido, o browser não envia o campo no POST... ai nunca vai ter $_POST['send']...

Comment: Bom, Ok então rs nem testei aqui! Eu já passei por essa situação há muito tempo atrás e preferi por padrão sempre definir um value (mas acho que não era com o button meu problema), pode ser que as coisas mudaram ou eu que esteja me confundindo mesmo! Obrigado

Comment: E pelo jeito o autor da pergunta está ausente da comunidade rss

Comment: Beleza, acho que se confundiu com NAME, se não tiver name no input submit ai sim não vai dar certo. Nesse caso é melhor a opção 2 da sua resposta. if( isset($_POST) ){

Comment: Humm pode ser isso sim rs faz muito tempo!! E como usava JQuery com seletor pela ID, eu devia ter esquecido no name! Eu sou meio precavido, usaria: if( isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] === 'entrar' )) rs

Answer (score 0):

Seu código

```
  ........
  ........
 if(!empty($CPF) || !empty($NIS))
     {  
        $CPF = addslashes($_POST['CPF']);
        $NIS = addcslashes($_POST['NIS'])

  .......
  .......
```

Correto

```
 .......
 .......
 $CPF = addslashes($_POST['CPF']);
 $NIS = addcslashes($_POST['NIS'])

 if(!empty($CPF) || !empty($NIS))
     {  

  .......
  .......
```

Sendo assim se algum valor for enviado para CPF e/ou NIS deixarão de ser `empty` e entrarão no if